# Cant add video to Playlist

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I want to add a videos to an existing playlist using youtube:s API v2.

**i can add a new playlist** with videos and **i can modify a playlists description and title**. But nothing happens when i try to add videos to an existing playlist using the same codeblock. I got no error messages.

Here is my code:

```
public static Feed<Playlist> GetAllPlayLists(Video video)
        {
            var request = DoYouTubeRequest();
            Feed<Playlist> userPlaylists = request.GetPlaylistsFeed(Constants.YouTubeCompany);


            foreach (Playlist p in userPlaylists.Entries)
            {
                if (p.Title == "TEST")
                {
                    AddVideoToPlayList(video, p); // Nothings happens
                    p.Summary = "updated summary " + DateTime.Now; // This works
                    request.Update(p);
               }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static YouTubeRequest DoYouTubeRequest()
    {
        YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Test", Constants.YouTubeDeveloperKey, Constants.YoutubeUserName, Constants.YoutubePassword);
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
        return request;
    }

        public static void AddVideoToPlayList(Video video, Playlist playlist)
        {

        YouTubeRequest request =  DoYouTubeRequest();

        PlayListMember pm = new PlayListMember();
        pm.VideoId = video.VideoId;

            try
            {
                request.AddToPlaylist(playlist, pm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception in function AddVideoToPlayList:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

      public static Playlist CreatePlaylist(string title, string summary, Video v)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("title and/or summary is null or empty");
        }

        var request = DoYouTubeRequest();

        Playlist pl = new Playlist();
        pl.Title = title;
        pl.Summary = summary;

        Playlist createdPlaylist = request.Insert(new Uri("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists"), pl);
        AddVideoToPlayList(v, createdPlaylist);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: That looks like it should work.